# If the MLE of $\theta$ is $\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{\bar{X}}$, what would be the asymptotic variance $\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\theta})$?

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood

For instance, we would could have as a distributions $f_X(x) = \theta e^{\theta x}$.
In this case it is a exponential distribution, and would our parameter be the usual $\beta = \frac{1}{\theta}$, $\operatorname{Var}(\widehat{\beta_\text{MLE}}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ and it is easy to calculate, but because here $\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{\bar{X}}$, the inversion of $X$ is what makes it tricky... (I have no idea how to calculate $\operatorname{Var}(\frac{1}{\bar{X}})$)

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(Y_k)$ is i.i.d. standard exponential, that is, with PDF $$f(y)=e^{-y}\mathbf 1_{y>0}$$ then, for every $n\geqslant1$, $T_n=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$ has PDF $$f_n(t)=\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-t}\mathbf 1_{t>0}$$ hence, for every $n\geqslant2$, $$E\left((T_n)^{-1}\right)=\frac1{n-1}$$ and, for every $n\geqslant3$, $$E\left((T_n)^{-2}\right)=\frac1{(n-1)(n-2)}$$ hence $$\mathrm{Var}\left((T_n)^{-1}\right)=\frac1{(n-1)^2(n-2)}$$ Now, each of your random variables $X_k$ is distributed like $Y_k/\theta$ hence your $\bar X_n$ is distributed like $$\frac1{n\theta}T_n$$ hence, for every $n\geqslant3$, $$\mathrm{Var}\left((\bar X_n)^{-1}\right)=\frac{n^2\theta^2}{(n-1)^2(n-2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\bar{X}$ is the mean of your data, with CLT assumptions we have that $\bar{X}$ is asymptotically normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. You can then approximate:

$$\frac{1}{\bar{X}}\approx \frac{1}{\mu}-\frac{1}{\mu}(\bar{X}-\mu)+\frac{1}{\mu^2}(\bar{X}-\mu)^2+...$$

Now proceed to calculate the variance by squaring the above and keeping terms up to order $X^2$.

$$E[\frac{1}{\bar{X}^2}]\approx \frac{1}{\mu^2}+\frac{1}{\mu^2}\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+\frac{1}{\mu^3}\sigma^2/n+O(1/n^2),$$

$$E[1/\bar{X}]\approx 1/\mu+\frac{\sigma^2/n}{\mu^2},$$

which will give you an approximation to $\mbox{Var}(\theta)$. Note that if $\bar{X}$ is exactly normal, then the expectation and variance of $1/\bar{X}$ will actually blow up, so you need some strong assumptions on either $\bar{X}$ being bounded away from zero, or decaying sufficiently fast near 0.

Comment: "which will give you an approximation to Var(θ)." Sorry but we do not know that, the rigor of the preceding steps being much lacking.

Comment: @Did: I would think the Delta Method is rigorous enough to fill in the blanks here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method

I do agree that you need more assumptions about $\bar{X}$ being either bounded away from 0 or at least decaying in probability sufficiently fast.

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you very much for mentionning the Delta method ! Indeed, I was trying to get the variance in order to get the asymptotic distribution of the variable : Using the Delta method, it is actually very easy. 

It solves my problem !

Comment: @Eizan: Which asymptotics did you reach, doing so?

Comment: Well, the CLT tells us that the asymptotic distribution of $\bar{X}$ follows, in the case of the example exponential distribution I gave earlier, $N(\frac{1}{\theta}, \frac{1}{n\theta^2 })$, and apply the Delta method, afaik $g(u) = \frac{1}{u}$ and $g'(u) = \frac{-1}{u^2}$, so we would have that $\hat{\theta}$ follows a $N(\theta, \frac{g'(\frac{1}{\theta})^2}{n\theta^2})$, $N(\theta, \frac{\theta^2}{n})$, that is, if I don't suck at calculus, what I know I do

Comment: @EizanPrime: Simulating a million averages of $n = 5$ observations from an exponential with rate $\theta = 2$ approximated the variance as 2.084 which is well within the margin of simulation error of Did's variance formula (2.083). What numerical answer do you get in this case?